# Saving, extracting relevant data from cell arrays in multiple loops in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, structure, signal-processing, cell-array

sorry for asking may be this is simple question but I am stuck in it. It’s related to cell arrays.

I have `delay, offset, and threshold.`

```
 delay = [0.01:0.01:0.03];
 offset = [0.02:0.01:0.04];
 threshold = [0.4:0.1:0.9];       
 limit_for_idx  = [0.4:0.1:0.9]; 
 limit = [0.4:0.1:0.9];
```

I have tried to provide an example to ask only a part where I have some issue.

In first part of loop I have received complete values for Delay, Offset, J, r, threshold as shown in figure for all loops.

`delay =0.0300` `offset=0.0400` `J=16 25 24 25`  `r = 24 21 46 18` `threshold = 0.4:0.9`

[image]

Then I filtered Minimum value of J and maximum value of r and threshold values which corresponds to min J and max r. I have received these values as shown in figure.

```
   [min_J,min_J_loc] = min(J(:))
   [max_r,max_r_loc] = max(r(:))
   thresh_min_J = threshold(min_J_loc);
   thresh_max_r = threshold(max_r_loc);
```

[image]

For the one case I have marked with red but I will receive these combinations for all loops like shown in whole picture.

**Questions:**

•   I want to find the combination of `delay, offset, threshold` which contains `minimum J` and `maximum r` **as shown in figure** from all the combinations I need I need the combination of `delay` ,`offset`, `threshold` which contain  `minimum J` and `maximum r` . I have saved values in the cell array as I am confused that how to get the combination out of cell array.

•   Is there any good approach to save the values or may be structures if yes can someone explain how just small hint will also work.

**Code :**

```
 delay = [0.01:0.01:0.03];
 offset = [0.02:0.01:0.04];
 threshold = [0.4:0.1:0.9];       
 limit_for_idx  = [0.4:0.1:0.9]; 
 limit = [0.4:0.1:0.9];         


 J=0;
 T = 1;
 b=1;
 K=1;
 for H = 1:numel(delay)
     for G = 1:numel(offset)
        for R = 1:numel(threshold);  

          J = randi([10 25],1,4);    
           r = randi([10 50],1,4);
        end
   [min_J,min_J_loc] = min(J(:))
   [max_r,max_r_loc] = max(r(:))
   thresh_min_J = threshold(min_J_loc);
   thresh_max_r = threshold(max_r_loc);
       out{K,:} = [ delay(H) offset(G)  J  r threshold];
       output{T,:} = [delay(H) offset(G)  min_J  max_r  thresh_min_J  thresh_max_r];
     K=K+1;
     T = T+1;
     end

 end


  for X = 1:numel(out)
      disp(' delay ,   offset(G) ,  J,   r ,  threshold  ') 
      Q = out{X};
      disp(Q)
  end

   for X = 1:numel(output)
        disp(' delay ,   offset(G) ,  min_J,   max_r ,   thresh_min_J  thresh_max_r ')
      Z =  output{X};
      disp(Z)

   end
```

Comment: When you say "_which contains `minimum J` and `maximum r` as shown in figure_". Do you mean the `thresh`? Because neither the `J` is minimal nor the `r` maximal... Does the image with the red frame show the result of finding the min/max values? It's a bit confusing...

Comment: Please have a look at first attached figure.
It contains values for `J´ and ´r` like.
0.0300    0.0400   `16.0000   25.0000   24.0000   25.0000`    r  `24.0000   21.0000   46.0000   18.0000` threshold `  
0.4000    0.5000    0.6000    0.7000    0.8000    0.9000`

Comment: Then I applied logic to filter out min J and max r value from it I got 
`delay ,   offset(G) ,  min_J,   max_r ,   thresh_min_J  thresh_max_r `
    `0.0300    0.0400   16.0000   46.0000    0.4000    0.6000`

Comment: Then I want to find out the overall best combination from all the filtered combinations.
Like in figure the combination that contains min J is 
`delay ,   offset(G) ,  min_J,   max_r ,   thresh_min_J  thresh_max_r 
    0.0100    0.0200   10.0000   40.0000    0.5000    0.5000`

Comment: And combination that contains max r is 
`delay ,   offset(G) ,  min_J,   max_r ,   thresh_min_J  thresh_max_r 
    0.0300    0.0300   10.0000   48.0000    0.5000    0.4000`
I want to find these from cell arrays

Comment: I think you should post this on [codereview.se] seeing how this is working code, and you're looking for comments and improvement suggestions (and I can see quite a few things that can be improved here - which is a good thing!).

Comment: Sorry for a bit confusing stuff.
I have updated a new picture may be it will help.
I have **red box** which contains combination with `min J`.
I have marked **blue box** which contain combination with `max r`.
I need to filter these from all the combinations that cell array has and also need a good way to save the values I used cell array but it is a bit confusing for lay man .

Comment: Plz have a look at it now if my explanation works so may be if you have time you can provide me an answer otherwise i will drop this qurrey on code review as i have never used code review before so may be it takes some time and you are right this code needs some changes for handling and storing stuffs.Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What is your expected output for the given example? The red box or the blue box?

Comment: Both boxes `red box` because it contains `min J` and `Blue box` as it contains `max r`

Comment: @Peter What is your MATLAB version?

Comment: Right now I am using R 2012b but I have also R 2015 in my home laptop so it will work if you use some upgraded commands

Comment: @Peter In the case of your example, `min_J` is found in both variables. If several rows share `min_J` or `max_r`, what would you like to output? All rows? Just the first? Just the last?

Comment: @Dev-iL thanks a lot for your proceedings . All rows that contains `max_r` and all rows that contains `min_ J` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this modified version of your example:

```
function varargout = q47452082
delay = (0.01:0.01:0.03);
offset = (0.02:0.01:0.04);
threshold = (0.4:0.1:0.9);
nD = numel(delay);
nO = numel(offset);
J = randi([10 25],1,4,nD,nO);
r = randi([10 50],1,4,nD,nO);
%% Preallocate
%{
The simplest way to do it:
out    = NaN(nD*nO,3*1+2*4);
output = NaN(nD*nO,6);
%}
out = struct('delay',[],'offset',[],'J',[],'r',[],'threshold',[]);
out = repmat(out,nD*nO,1);
output = struct('delay',[],'offset',[],'min_J',[],'max_r',[],...
  'thresh_min_J',[],'thresh_max_r',[]);
output = repmat(output,nD*nO,1);
fn{2} = fieldnames(output);
fn{1} = fieldnames(out);
%% Populate the data structures:
K = 1;
for H = 1:numel(delay)
  for G = 1:numel(offset)
    [min_J,min_J_loc] = min(J(:,:,H,G));
    [max_r,max_r_loc] = max(r(:,:,H,G));
    thresh_min_J = threshold(min_J_loc);
    thresh_max_r = threshold(max_r_loc);
    data = {delay(H),offset(G),J(:,:,H,G),r(:,:,H,G),threshold};
    for indF = 1:numel(fn{1})
      out(K).(fn{1}{indF}) = data{indF};
    end
    data = {delay(H), offset(G), min_J, max_r, thresh_min_J, thresh_max_r};
    for indF = 1:numel(fn{2})
      output(K).(fn{2}{indF}) = data{indF};
    end
    K = K+1;
  end
end

if nargout == 0 % if no outputs requested, print
  if ~verLessThan('matlab','8.2') % tables exist in MATLAB R2013b or newer
    disp(struct2table(out));
    disp(struct2table(output));
  else
    for X = 1:numel(out)
      Q = out(X);
      disp(Q)
    end
    for X = 1:numel(output)
      Z = output(X);
      disp(Z)
    end
  end
else % otherwise output the desired data:
  % OPTION #1: separate variables
  % You should call the function like so: [min_J_cases,max_r_cases] = q47452082();
  varargout{1} = output([output.min_J] == min([output.min_J]));
  varargout{2} = output([output.max_r] == max([output.max_r]));
  % OPTION #2: 1 output, 2x1 cell
  %{
  varargout = {output([output.min_J] == min([output.min_J]));...
               output([output.max_r] == max([output.max_r]))};
  %}
  % OPTION #3: 1 output, 2x1 struct
  %{
  varargout = {[output([output.min_J] == min([output.min_J]));...
                output([output.max_r] == max([output.max_r]))]};
  %}
end
```

Several things you should note:

- I removed some unused variables.
- I preallocated `out` and `output` as `struct` arrays.
- I removed the loop around the `J`,`r` randomization (since it does nothing) and moved the random number generation to before the loop (no reason to do it in every iteration when it can be done all at once at the beginning).
- I perform assignment using [dynamic field references](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) to both `struct` arrays.
- I added a demonstration of how to run different code depending on different MATLAB version (and hence, different supported functionality) - see printing at the end.
- The function only prints things if you don't request outputs.
- There is likely room for further vectorization of your code (i.e. getting rid of loops).

Comment: thanks a lot for your elaborated reply.Please just give me sometime to have a look at the code deeply and i will get back to you if I have some issue and thanks a lot for your time and guidance.

Comment: @De-Vil  first of all really sorry for late feedback. Thanks  lot for your solution. It worked. I modified it further according to my needs but it is working perfectly. Thanks a lot for your time and guidance.